# How to increase the microphone sample rate on problematic phones

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, xiaomi

I working on a web app that shows a graph based on the microphone samples. I take the highest value of the vector return from getByteTimeDomainData each ~15ms and put it on a graph.

The problem is that in some phones (such as Xiaomi phones) I get fake microphone samples- it returns the same vector 10 times (~150ms), and only after that it samples the microphone again and returns a new vector for another 10 times.

**Standart phones:**

Highest values collected from 30 calls to getByteTimeDomainData:
230,237,237,236,236,220,220,232,232,218,218,214,214,217,217,227,227,222,222,224,224,222,222,216,216,202,202,223,223,205

[image: Standart phones graph]

**Xiaomi phones:**

Highest values collected from 30 calls to getByteTimeDomainData:
**132,132,132,132,132,132,132**,129,129,129,129,129,129,129,129,129,129,**130,130,130,130,130,130,130,130,130,130**,131,131,131

[image: Xiaomi phones graph]

My question is- How can I improve it and get more samples in Xiaomi?

```
var start_amp = function () {
    'use strict';

    var soundAllowed = function (stream) {
        window.persistAudioStream = stream;
        var audioContext = new AudioContext();
        var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

        audioStream.connect(analyser);

        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0; // = 1 doesn't fix the samples problem
        analyser.fftSize = 1024;

        var frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

        var doDraw = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(doDraw);
            analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray);

            var max = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < frequencyArray.length; i++) {
                if (max < frequencyArray[i]) {
                    max = frequencyArray[i];
                }
            }

            boardArray.push(max);

            if (boardArray.length >= document.body.clientWidth * 0.7) {
                boardArray.shift();
                totalSamples += 1;
                if (totalSamples == 60) {
                    totalSamples = 0;
                }
            }

            draw(boardArray);
        }
        doDraw();
    }

    var soundNotAllowed = function (error) {
        alert('Please check your microphone connectivity and allow this site to access it');
        console.log(error);
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, soundAllowed, soundNotAllowed);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the [sampleRate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContextOptions/sampleRate) on the `AudioContextOptions`?

Comment: I'm quite sure that the microphone sampling hardware is not capable of collecting more samples physically. So to match your desired sample rate, values are just repeated (no interpolation). You'd need to come up with some interpolation techniques to smooth out the signal, however, you won't increase the bandwidth though.

Comment: @StevenB. the return value of audioContext.sampleRate is 48000Hz for all devices. I changed it with AudioContextOptions to other rates and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @Psi I think it doesn't make sense that Xiaomi phones cannot exceed 6Hz (=~150ms) microphone sample rate...

Comment: I don't think that you get the samples for the actual time you request them but rather get a continuous output of samples. I.e.: Even if you request the samples 150ms later, the buffer will just output the next samples it recorded. And these ones are repeated. Normally, for telephone calls, you don't need frequencies above 2kHz, so a sample rate of 4800 Hz is enough to produce these (therefore the 10 repetitions => scaling up to 48kHz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that creating another AudioContext and Analyser gives me different samples. Looks like there is some sample rate limit for each node.
So I created 3 AudioContext's and used the average of them:

[image]

```js
var start_amp = function () {
    'use strict';

    var soundAllowed = function (stream) {
        window.persistAudioStream = stream;

        // Node 1
        var audioContext = new AudioContext();
        var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

        audioStream.connect(analyser);

        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0; // = 1 doesn't fix the samples problem
        analyser.fftSize = 1024;

        // Node 2
        var audioContext2 = new AudioContext();
        var audioStream2 = audioContext2.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var analyser2 = audioContext2.createAnalyser();

        audioStream2.connect(analyser2);

        analyser2.smoothingTimeConstant = 0; // = 1 doesn't fix the samples problem
        analyser2.fftSize = 1024;

        // Node 3
        var audioContext3 = new AudioContext();
        var audioStream3 = audioContext3.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var analyser3 = audioContext3.createAnalyser();

        audioStream3.connect(analyser3);

        analyser3.smoothingTimeConstant = 0; // = 1 doesn't fix the samples problem
        analyser3.fftSize = 1024;

        var frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        var frequencyArray2 = new Uint8Array(analyser2.frequencyBinCount);
        var frequencyArray3 = new Uint8Array(analyser3.frequencyBinCount);

        var doDraw = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(doDraw);
            analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray);
            analyser2.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray2);
            analyser3.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyArray3);

            var max = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < frequencyArray.length; i++) {
                if (max < frequencyArray[i]) {
                    max = frequencyArray[i];
                }
            }

            var max2 = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < frequencyArray2.length; i++) {
                if (max2 < frequencyArray2[i]) {
                    max2 = frequencyArray2[i];
                }
            }

            var max3 = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < frequencyArray3.length; i++) {
                if (max3 < frequencyArray3[i]) {
                    max3 = frequencyArray3[i];
                }
            }

            boardArray.push((max + max2 + max3) / 3);

            if (boardArray.length >= document.body.clientWidth * 0.7) {
                boardArray.shift();
                totalSamples += 1;
                if (totalSamples == 60) {
                    totalSamples = 0;
                }
            }

            draw(boardArray);
        }
        doDraw();
    }

    var soundNotAllowed = function (error) {
        alert('Please check your microphone connectivity and allow this site to access it');
        console.log(error);
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, soundAllowed, soundNotAllowed);
}
```